# Python array manipulation using numpy

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy

I am trying to replicate the border of a array:

```
A=[1,2],[3,4]
```

and want the result as

```
[1,1,1,2,2,2]
[1,1,1,2,2,2]
[1,1,1,2,2,2]
[3,3,3,4,4,4]
[3,3,3,4,4,4]
[3,3,3,4,4,4]
```

How do you do it in python? I am using

```
import numpy
(a,2,reflect') or wrap I am not getting this array
```

Comment: When you say "replicate the border", what exactly does that mean? Your example input is nothing but corners, so it doesn't show us what should happen to edges or interior elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested `repeat` method (example in [IPython](http://ipython.org/)):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

In [3]: A.repeat(3, 1).repeat(3, 0)
Out[3]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

But for image manipulation you migth want to have a look at e.g:

- [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) (or the newer variant, [pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))
- Python [interfaces](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) to the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite

Especially ImageMagick provides a lot of image manipulation tools.

Comment: There's also a `repeat` method, which will likely be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have numpy 1.7 or later, you can use [`np.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html), with `mode='edge'`:

```
In [8]: a
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

In [9]: np.pad(a, pad_width=2, mode='edge')
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]])
```

Comment: This does something completely different from the other answer, but with the current state of the question, it's difficult to tell whether either answer is right, and which is right, if any.